# Seaborn will not update to latest version in Conda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, seaborn

Seaborn will not update to the latest version (0.11.0) in Anaconda. When doing a conda search seaborn, the 0.10.0, 0.10.1, and 0.11.0 versions are listed, but the associated build is listed as py_0 for each. When attempting to update in Anaconda, version 0.9.0 remains.

How can I go about getting the latest version? I've tried installing via pip and conda-forge to no avail (conda-forge fails when solving environment).

Thank you!

Comment: are you working in your base environment? try creating a new one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### `seaborn v0.12.0`

`conda install seaborn=0.12` - This option works if the seaborn version is available on the `channels` specified in the `.condarc` file. See [Managing channels](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html).

or

`conda update -c conda-forge seaborn` - specify a channel

---

### `seaborn v0.11`

`conda install seaborn=0.11.0`

If that doesn't work, create a new environment and do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this:

pip install --upgrade seaborn

Comment: Creating a new environment was not an option for me. Also conda install seaborn=0.11.0 did not work since many conflicts occured. Therefore, uprating @Alexandres answer.